# ClickToPlugin alike for Firefox?

Tags: safari, firefox, safari-extensions

I recently stumbled upon [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/). Its power is making me think about switching from Safari to Firefox. However there are some Safari extensions I really find useful.

- [ClickToPlugin](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/)
- [Reddit and MacRumors Minimal](http://www.cornellcampbell.com/extensions/)

I can live without the minimal extensions, however ClickToPlugin is really useful. It for once disables all flash content on the webpage, and when clicked transforms the flash content to an HTML5 video.

Do we have an equivalent ClickToPlugin extension for Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

## **[NoScript](http://noscript.net/features#contentblocking)**

...can block plugins which you enable *once* via click-to-play or *permanently* by white-listing domains that they load content from.

> While its primary aim is preventing malicious JavaScript from running, **NoScript effectively blocks Java™, Silverlight™, Flash®, and other plugins and embeddings** (such HTML video/audio elements and downloadable fonts) on sites you didn't explicitly whitelisted.
>
> Java Applets, Flash movies/applications, Quicktime clips, PDF documents and other content won't be even downloaded from sites where you consider them annoyances or dangers, saving your bandwidth and increasing your navigation speed.

NoScript's settings for blocking plug-ins can be found in:
*NoScript Preferences → Embedded Content*

Overall though, I'd not recommend this add-on if your goal it to merely to *reduce  noise*. NoScript has been written first to block javascript and it is a wonderful tool for that.
However, because it's so powerful and configurable, it can be difficult to use for newcomers and **takes a while to setup**.